# Returning a String in an Async Event Handler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, windows-phone-8

I need to return a String that I get from an Async Event Handler. I can't currently do this as if I try returning inside the handler, it gives me an error telling me I can't return any objects because the handler is supposed to return void.

Here is my code:

```
    public String Login(String username, String password)
    {
        String returningData = "";
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("user", username);
        parameters.Add("pass", password);

        PostClient client = new PostClient(parameters);
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (senders, ex) =>
            {
                if (ex.Error == null)
                {
                    //Process the result...
                    return ex.Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "An error occurred. The details of the error: " + ex.Error;
                }
            };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.site.com/sample.php", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

How can I return ex.Result/error message correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply fire an event to notify "outside world" about completion of operation.

For this define your delegate:

```
public void delegate OnError(object sender, string message);
public event OnError OnErrorEvent; 

...



           client.DownloadStringCompleted += (senders, ex) =>
            {
                if (ex.Error == null)
                {
                    //Process the result...
                    return ex.Result;
                }
                else
                {
                   if(OnErrorEvent != null)
                   OnErrorEvent(this, "An error occurred. The details of the error: " + ex.Error;);
                }
            };
```

This is just an example, you have to choose more approriate signature of delegate for your concrete case.

Comment: Hmm... good idea! I don't know why I couldn't think of this before.

Comment: You'll need either two events, one for the error case and one for the success case, or an event with enough information to handle either case through its arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can have the method return a `Task<string>` rather than a string.  The method won't return a value right when it's called, calling the method will start the work and the task can be completed at some point in the future.  You can use a `TaskCompletionSource` to create the task to be returned.

```
public Task<string> Login(String username, String password)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("user", username);
    parameters.Add("pass", password);

    PostClient client = new PostClient(parameters);
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (senders, ex) =>
    {
        if (ex.Error == null)
        {
            //Process the result...
            tcs.TrySetResult(ex.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessage = "An error occurred. The details of the error: " + ex.Error;
            //todo use a more derived exception type
            tcs.TrySetException(new Exception(errorMessage));
        }
    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://inkyapps.mobilemp.net/scripts/PHP/socialnet/login.php", UriKind.Absolute));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Does Windows Phone 8 support the Task class? System.Threading.Tasks doesn't exist...

Comment: @AndrewKim It should, yes, but I'm not a winphone developer, so I'm not really sure what might be different about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this up into a `Task<string>`, and return that:

```
public Task<string> LoginAsync(String username, String password)
{
    var results = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("user", username);
    parameters.Add("pass", password);

    PostClient client = new PostClient(parameters);
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (senders, ex) =>
        {
            if (ex.Error == null)
            {
                results.TrySetResult(ex.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                results.TrySetException(ex.Error); // Set the exception
            }
        };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://inkyapps.mobilemp.net/scripts/PHP/socialnet/login.php", UriKind.Absolute));

    return results.Task;
}
```

This will then allow you to use this method with the `async`/`await` keywords directly, providing proper asynchronous support and exception handling in the caller.